# ReferenceError in sailsjs application from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sails.js, dockerfile, sails-mongo

I am working on sails application In my application I have used **mysql** and **mongo** adpater to connect with different database. Both db are hosted on somewhere on internet. Application is working fine in my local environment. I am facing issue once I add project to docker container. I am able to generate docker image and run docker container. When I call simple routers where DB connection is not exists it's working fine but when I call **Testcontroller** which is return data from mongodb. it give me `ReferenceError: Test is not define.` here `Test` is mongodb's entity.

DockerFile:

```
FROM node:latest
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "./"]
RUN npm install --verbose --force && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD npm start
```

TestController

```
/**
 * TestController
 * @description :: Server-side actions for handling incoming requests.
 *
 * @help        :: See https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/actions
 */

module.exports = {
  index: async function(req, res) {
    var data = await Test.find(); // Here I am getting error Test is not define.
    res.json(data);
  }
};
```

Routes.js

```
'GET /test': {controller:'test', action:'index'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found issue I am moving **node_modules** to previous directory that is the issue.

below Configuration works for me.

```
FROM node:latest
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "./"]
RUN npm install --verbose --force
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD npm start
```